# Blackscreen on 27” iMac 2017

Tags: imac, power

I own a iMac 27” retina 2017.

It won’t turn on again. The screen is black and stays black when turn the iMac on and off.

I even hear nothing when I turn the Mac on. No click sound, no chime, nothing.

But now “The strangest thing”…

When I connect a USB lightbulb to the Mac, the lightbulb works! I can even charge my iPhone when I connect it with a USB lightning cable to the iMac.

So, when I turn the iMac on, the USB  lightbulb lights up when I push the button to turn the Mac on, and the USB  lightbulb goes off when I hold the turn on button at least 6 seconds.

That’s the only sign of life of my iMac.

Can anyone tell me what to do, else than trowing away the iMac or bring it in for a $$$ repair…

Answer (score 2):

You iMac has died and based on the description, it’s the power supply or something related to power distribution.  It needs to go in for repairs.

> When I connect a usb lightbulb to the Mac, the lightbulb works!

This is entirely possible.  The power supply puts ot several voltages  via *power rails* and this includes a 5V rail to power things like USB ports.  There’s a 3V rail for use by processors including the CPU and even a 48V (varies depending on application) for the video.  It appears this 5V rail still works.

This is not something you can fix.  It must be disassembled and diagnosed as to the cause of why a 5V rail is working, but not the 12V and/or 3V rail.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem. Led 3 and 4 will not lightup.

I have contacted a Apple repair service and their judgement was not what I wanted to hear.

The Mac has a problem with the video powersupply as the 3th. led will not light up. Probably, the video card corrupt or death. As the 4th. led also will not light up, there even might be another problem. The powersupply is ok, the fan works, usb outlets work as well as far they are able to charge an iPhone or else.

The verdict: your Mac has probaby died by a power management faciliteiten in the Logic board. Your iMac needs a new Logic board and maybe a new SSD and or RAM as well. Concerning the screen, we only know of that has to be replaced when we installed a new logicboard.

It will cost more money to repair than buying a refurbished one.

So,… so far the life of my iMac 27” Retina w. SSD, only private used once a week for Photo editing since november 2017.

Don’t think I buy a new iMac again. It was a expensive computer and died just after 5 years and a few months.

Thank you all for your input.

Comment: "It will cost more money to repair than buying a refurbished one." - Yup, that is normal for Apple. Apple makes the repairs really expensive because you have no choice and they want you to buy a new one. There are some unofficial places that can repair it properly for cheaper, but not many. I do not understand why anybody buys Apple products. If this problem happened on a different computer, you would most likely still need to replace the logic board, but it would be cheaper.